# Flutter - Bloc initial event not returning state

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm getting started with flutter bloc. I have a splash screen with added a logic to check whether the user is logged in or not..

Bloc

```
class SplashBloc extends Bloc<SplashEvent, SplashState> {
  final supabaseClient = Supabase.instance.client;
  Session? userSession;
  SplashBloc() : super(SplashInitialState()) {
    on<SplashInitialEvent>(listenAuthState);
  }

  StreamSubscription<AuthState> listenAuthState(
      SplashInitialEvent event, Emitter<SplashState> emit) {
    debugPrint("Initial Call Triggered"); // this line prints on initial
    return supabaseClient.auth.onAuthStateChange.listen((data) {
      final Session? session = data.session;
      final AuthChangeEvent event = data.event;
      switch (event) {
        case AuthChangeEvent.passwordRecovery:
          break;
        case AuthChangeEvent.signedIn:
          return emit(SignedInState());
        case AuthChangeEvent.signedOut:
          return emit(NotSignedInState()); // trying to emit this event.
        case AuthChangeEvent.tokenRefreshed:
          break;
        case AuthChangeEvent.userUpdated:
          break;
        case AuthChangeEvent.userDeleted:
          break;
        case AuthChangeEvent.mfaChallengeVerified:
          break;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The listenAuthState is getting triggered. how ever im not getting any state back.

UI

```
return BlocProvider<SplashBloc>(
  create: (context) => SplashBloc()..add(SplashInitialEvent()),
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        return BlocListener(
          bloc: BlocProvider.of<SplashBloc>(context),
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is NotSignedInState) {
              debugPrint('state is notsignedstate');
              context.go('/onboarding');
            } else {
              context.go('/home');
            }
          },
          child: Center(
            child: Lottie.asset(splashLottied),
          ),
        );
      }
    ),
  ),
);
```

Is this the correct way to emit a state? if not what will be the correct way to emit a state and use routing based on in bloc?

Comment: i guess, you attach to the `onAuthStateChange.listen` but you return the `listenAuthState`  when you subscribe to the listener, so the `emit` function is not working anymore

Comment: @dstreissi so what would be the correct way to emit a state in this scenario?

Comment: You have to emit a SplashState, but you are returning a StreamSubscription<AuthState> ?

Comment: check out this article, see section Bloc and stream: https://verygood.ventures/blog/how-to-use-bloc-with-streams-and-concurrency